# Why do these two regexes behave differently?

Tags: regex, perl

Why do the following two regexes behave differently?

```
$millisec = "1391613310.1";
$millisec =~  s/.*(\.\d+)?$/$1/;
```

vs.

```
$millisec =~  s/\d*(\.\d+)?$/$1/;
```

This code prints nothing:

```
perl -e 'my $mtime = "1391613310.1"; my $millisec = $mtime; $millisec =~  s/.*(\.\d+)?$/$1/;  print "$millisec";'
```

While this prints the decimal portion of the string:

```
perl -e 'my $mtime = "1391613310.1"; my $millisec = $mtime; $millisec =~  s/\d*(\.\d+)?$/$1/;  print "$millisec";'
```

Comment: Those are not milliseconds, by the way; 0.1 seconds is 100 milliseconds.

Comment: could you not write it more cleanly? to catch .1 and 1.1, though  I am not sure what you want the decimal or the whole number. Looks like the decimal.  So for all '/(\d+.d+)$/$1/;' I love the use of the memory and the use of '\d' over '[0-9]' of just the decimal '/\d+(\.\d+)$/$1/' ;  Though the intent is a bit confused other than asking why they match differently.

Comment: Hi Alex - Yes I want the decimal. Did you mean "how I wrote the post" Or "the regular expression"? Can you suggest simpler regex(if its about that)?
.
Triplee - you are right. I did not mention that I use sprintf later to append zeros.

Answer (score 8):

In the first regex, the `.*` is taking up everything to the end of the string, so there's nothing the optional `(.\d+)?` can pick up. `$1` will be empty, so the string is replaced by an empty string.

In the second regex, only digits are grabbed from the beginning so that `\d*` stops in front of the dot. `(.\d+)?` will pick the dot, including the trailing digits.

You're using `.\d+` inside parentheses, which will match any character plus digits. If you want to match a dot explicitly, you have to use `\.`.

To make the first regex behave similarly to the second one you would have to write

```
$millisec =~  s/.*?(\.\d+)?$/$1/;
```

so that the initial `.*` doesn't take up everything.

Answer (score 1):

Greed.

Perl's regex engine will match as much as possible with each term before moving on to the next term. So for `.*(.\d+)?$` the `.*` matches the entire string, then `(.\d)?` matches nothing as it is optional.

`\d*(.\d+)?$` can match only up to the dot, so then has to match `.1` against `(.\d+)?`

Comment: The key part is that `(\.\d+)` is *optional*.

Comment: Hi Borodin - why "\d*" is not greedy while ".*" is greedy?